# Why request is being served before the request pipeline completes (or middleware function ends)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, middleware

I am developing a custom middleware for serving static content from wwwroot folder (I know there exists a predefined middleware for this).

But before termination of middleware's InvokeAsync method, the request is served to the client. How it is possible? Since, for serving the request to client, it should complete the request pipeline.

Below I have 2 snapshot at an instance when `await fs.CopyToAsync(context.Response.Body);` is just executed and control is moved to next line (line no. 428) (note: middleware InvokeAsync is not completed yet).

[image: Control is at line no. 428]

[image: about.txt server to the client]